# Status Monitoring In Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, timeout, monitoring, logout, status

How can i solve session timeout problem, I am monitoring my project status through "Status Monitor Plugin" and I used jenkins auto refresh plugin , more than 5 auto refresh plugin in mozilla but it no one worked for me . Is there any suggestion?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `session timeout problem`? I do not understand your problem.

Comment: jenkins user session downs, we are monitoring project status 24h in one screen and jenkins needs login after 2 hour

Answer (score 0):

Under "Configure Global Security" there is a checkbox named "Enable Single SignOut" whenever the user logs out of CAS (e.g. when logging out of another CAS-enabled application), the corresponding Jenkins session will be destroyed and the local user logged out as well.